# Size of data that can be written to / read from sockets

Tags: linux, files, socket

I was wondering if there is an easy way to find the maximum size that is supported by Linux sockets? (Is this configurable? If so where?)

For example, most of the socket examples found on the web send "Hello Socket" or some such other small string, however if I put the whole of *War And Peace* into the socket, when does it break?

As everything is a file, is it the maximum file size? How is it coordinated when sockets connect different file systems?

I'm most interested in stream sockets.

Comment: Re _War & Piece_: be mindful of the `EFELL_ASLEEP` error code from `read`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.wmem_max` are your thing.
You can examine their values with

```
# sysctl net.core.rmem_max
```

and set them with

```
# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
```

These are the socket buffer sizes, when receiving and sending, respectively.
They have default values, too, - `rmem_default` and `wmem_default`.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't say what type of sockets.

### Stream sockets

You can send (by definition) an unlimited amount of data. If it cannot all be buffered or sent at once or if the receiver cannot receive it all at once, the send will either block (for blocking sockets) or return a partial count of bytes written or `EAGAIN` (for nonblocking sockets).

### Datagram sockets

It depends on the protocol. UDPv4 supports only 65536 bytes per datagram. UDPv6 supports much more. UNIX domain sockets probably support still more: you are probably just limited by memory in this case.

Comment: Stream Sockets Actually - Although i didnt know there would be a difference.

Comment: -1 for 'unlimited amount of data' comment.